# Challenges Encountered in Retrieving Information Using Token Authentication in a Django REST API

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Challenges Encountered in Retrieving Information Using Token Authentication in a Django REST API**

Experiencing Difficulty Performing GET and POST Operations with Token Authentication for Data Retrieval

This is my views.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Student
from .serlizer import StudentSerlilizer
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated



class StudentInfo(APIView):

    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]  # Apply TokenAuthentication
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]  # Apply IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly permission

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        stu = Student.objects.all()
        serlizer = StudentSerlilizer(stu,many=True)
        return Response(serlizer.data)
    
    def post(self,request,format=None):
        request_data = request.data
        serlizer = StudentSerlilizer(data=request_data)
        if serlizer.is_valid():
            serlizer.save()
            msg = {'msg':'Your data has been saved'}
            return Response(msg)
        
        msg = {'msg':serlizer.errors}
        return Response(msg,status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And this is my urls:-

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
# from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView,TokenRefreshView,TokenVerifyView

urlpatterns = [
    # path('authtoken/',obtain_auth_token),
    path('gettoken/',TokenObtainPairView.as_view(),name="get_token"),
    path('refreshtoken/',TokenRefreshView.as_view(),name="refresh_token"),
    path('verifytoken/',TokenVerifyView.as_view(),name="verify_token"),
    path('studentinfo/',views.StudentInfo.as_view(),name="studentlist"),
    path('studentinfo/<int:pk>/',views.StudentRUD.as_view(),name="StudentRUD")
]
```

When i tried to get the values by using Tokenauth, i'm getting this error:

{
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}

This is how i tried to Get the values:-

```
http GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/studentinfo/ 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjk1MzYxMTk5LCJpYXQiOjE2OTUzNjA4OTksImp0aSI6ImY1ODY1MWE5NjMwNTRhMDA4MzA6NTFmZTJmMzU1MTgwIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MX0.GmlHfKR59s6SUDEI_ZHardNDDH7T_lEWYJlIBxc3LmI'
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 58
Content-Type: application/json
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Date: Fri, 22 Sep 2023 05:46:15 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.10.11
Vary: Accept
WWW-Authenticate: Token
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY

{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing auth mechanisms, I can see that `simplejwt package` is installed so you should use that and not `TokenAuthentication`.

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication #import this

authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
```

Or better yet just add this to your `settings.py` and remove `authentication_classes` from your views.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
)}
```